# AngularJS service function not returning promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, service, controller

I am fairly new to Angular so if you guys need more information let me know and I'll add it up here.

I have a controller that makes a function call to a service that *should* return some data retrieved by an HTTP.get function. However currently it doesn't seem to return any data or promise.

Here is the controller code that calls and handles the data from the service

```
var onRecentBlogPosts = function(data) {
    $scope.recentBlogPosts = data;
    $log.info($scope.recentBlogPosts);
    $log.info(JSON.stringify($scope.recentBlogPosts));
}

var onError = function(response) {
    $('.error-container').html("<div class='messages error'>Could not fetch the data. <br /><br />More information: <br />"+response+"</div>");
}

$q.when(backend.getRecentPosts).then(onRecentBlogPosts, onError);
```

I have also tried

```
backend.getRecentPosts.then(onRecentBlogPosts, onError);
//but then I get the error
TypeError: backend.getRecentProjects.then is not a function
```

The service 'backend' function that gets called is getRecentPosts

Service code:

```
(function() {
var backend = function($http, $q) {
    var getRecentPosts = function() {
        return $http.get("http://example.com/blog")
                    .then(function(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
    };

    return {
        getRecentPosts: getRecentPosts
    };
};


var module = angular.module("moduleName");
module.factory("backend", backend);

}());
```

When I look at the console (after the lines executed in the success function executes) I get

```
function getRecentPosts()
undefined
```

The goal here is to put all my http-related functions within the service then call it from different controllers. I am not sure if I should be receiving a promise or the data return from the http call or a combination of both.

So my bigger-picture question is:
How do I go about coding my service & service functions so that I can call them from different controllers and receive a promise/data?

Comment: As your `getRecentPosts` is a method, you should invoke that using `backend.getRecentPosts()` instead of `backend.getRecentPosts` because in the second case, it looks for property/field named `getRecentPosts` on backend object which it could not find, hence the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
backend.getRecentPosts().then(onRecentBlogPosts, onError);
```

You forgot to call the function. Also no need to have then inside factory

```
var getRecentPosts = function() {
        return $http.get("http://example.com/blog")
};
```